# Spring Boot 1.4.2, hibernate 5.2.3, Junit Test of repository, @DataJpaTest Issue, version conflict?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Boot, and I am trying to test a repository.
That is what I tried:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;
```

But I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>   ...
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>   ...
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53)
>   ...

I have some JUnit tests running without problems which only use the following annotations:

```
@ActiveProfiles("junit")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class MyControllerTest {
```

For the repository Junit test I need to use the TestEntityManager to make sure that the repository does it's job, and it seems like using @DataJpaTest is the way to do that. But as mentioned above, I am getting an exception.

I tried some other combinations of annotations but the exception did not go away.

In case it's my maven dependencies that are wrong, here they are:

```
<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    ....
</properties
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

As you can see, because of version conflicts I had to exclude the hibernate-entitymanager. Is that the reason why it's not working?

Could that mean that I have to switch back to an older version of hibernate to make this work?

I am pretty sure that the JUnit repository test needs my application-junit.properties file which defines settings for H2 DB with some specific tables, indexes and sequences. @DataJpaTest uses an auto-configured in-memory database. So here's another question: Will it make use of my create.h2.sql file to setup the schema? E.g. by reading the application-junit.properties automatically? This is the content:

```
# database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle;INIT=create schema if not exists testdb\\;SET SCHEMA testdb\\;runscript from 'classpath:create.h2.sql';
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

#datasource config
spring.database.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.database.jndi-name=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Thanks in advance if you know anything and let me know, too :) !

**UPDATE**

This is my SpringBootApplication class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many questions here and I guess we can answer all of them but it would be easier if you could focus on one problem. Do you want to know how to use `TestEntityManager` with `SpringBootTest`?

Comment: As I understood, I won't need to load the whole spring context if I want to test a repository, so I decided to use @DataJpaTest only, which loads only everything needed for repository tests, and not use SpringBootTest.  So my question is: Why does this not work for me?

Comment: You haven't explained what doesn't work. It would be 10 times faster if you share a project on github or something.

Comment: When I start the JUnit Repository Test with @DataJpaTest I always get the above mentioned exception (with or without SpringBootTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext / Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' / java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Comment: Ok, I edited the orignal post and changed the order of my questions to make things clearer.

Comment: show your `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: Sorry for the delay (it was Christmas ;)  ), I added my SpringBootApplication class.

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc`. Why are you doing this? it's useless unless you want to take full control over MVC configuration.

Comment: I found that I had to add spring-webmvc to be able to remove @EnableWebMvc. Now the exception is gone! But I still have to setup the db by using my create.h2.sql - how can I do this?

Comment: Your original question is now completely irrelevant so I am going to add an answer for what we've discussed. Please create another thread if you have another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@SpringBootApplication` has `@EnableWebMvc` on it. When you use a slice annotation (such as `@DataJpaTest`), Spring Boot finds the context to use by looking at the package of your test for a `@SpringBootConfiguration`. If it does not find one, it looks in the parent package, etc. With a sensible package structure and no further customization, your tests use your `@SpringBootApplication` as the root context.

`@EnableWebMvc` there is useless if you don't intend to take full control over the MVC setup, [see the documentation for more details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration).

In your case, this has an additional side effect: every single test now need to be web-based since *your are forcing* the mvc setup to kick in.

`TL;DR` never put such annotation on your application. And only put it if you actually need it.

Comment: Thanks to https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ I also found that I had to add spring-webmvc to make it work without @EnableWebMvc. Now the exception is gone.

Comment: I  don't know what you mean by "make it work without" but I don't think it is accurate. I've added a link to the documentation, please have a look to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Stephane!

Comment: Without spring-mvc I got some other exceptions, the entityManagerFactory was missing.

Comment: We should probably discuss this in chat (I think I got what your problem might be). Join us [on gitter if you want to discuss more](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot). but you should _not_ add that annotation in that context.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll could you please look this post and help out what is really missing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306755/getting-error-on-running-integration-and-datajpatest-together-org-springframewor